# PySpark / Python: Transforming dictionary python output into RDD / or other saveable (HDFS) formats

Tags: python, hadoop, dictionary, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm new to Spark / Pyspark / HDFS and I'm trying to load a .json-file directly from HDFS with the following code:

```
import json

file = sc.textFile('/path/to/HDFS/my.json')
data = file.map(lambda x: json.loads(x))
lis = data.collect()

... a lot of Python functions.
dictionary_output = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', ...}
```

After loading the file, I use some Python functions to process the data. The output after all these functions is dictionary as shown in the code. I now fail to save it back to HDFS as

```
dictionary_output.saveAsTextFile('/path/')
```

Doesn´t work for dictionaries. I also tried 'parallelizing' the dictionary, but then the output file only contained the key´s and no values.

So my question is: What is the right command to format the dictionary output into a 'RDD' or another file format that can be saved on HDFS with pyspark / python.

Comment: How do you want this data to be saved in HDFS? a pair "(k, v)" per line in a distributed text file or a distributed JSON file? Or some other format?

Comment: Is your final RDD is a `RDD[Dict]`? This is a way to convert this kind of file.

Comment: @DanieldePaula: I just found out that `sc.parallelize([dictionary_output]).saveAsTextFile('/path/')` does the deal. I guess this way its a "distributed text file"? What is a distributed JSON file, what are the benefits and how do I manage get one? 
@ThiagoBaldim: I tried your "RDD[Dict]" command just for curiosity but it didn´t work

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and the best approach in my case was to save the serialized dictionary as a JSON file back to HDFS.

You can do that by the following code:

```
sc = spark.sparkContext

spark.read.json(sc.parallelize([my_dict])).coalesce(1).write.mode('append').json('/hdfs_path')
```

Note that I found the need to use 'read.json' explicitly to avoid any errors/warning where PySpark tries to infer schema for the dictionary based on the column datatypes.